# Google Analytics traffic source attribution using Google Tag Manager (Legacy) SDK

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am looking to track **General Campaigns** (not install campaigns, but these ones [GA "General Campaigns" tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns)). When you create a deep link to your app and add UTM parameters so you can know from which source user has returned to your app (already installed).

Previously (GA SDK), we were using the *setCampaignParamsFromUrl* method which is not available for GTM SDK for some reason.

What's the best way to attack this, please? Also, does the next SDK version (v5 - Firebvase+Tag Manager SDK) solves this problem?

I know, I need to install receiver and intent to track install campaigns - I am after specifically *General Campaigns*